# Invoke RenamePrinter as a non-administrator user

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to rename a printer using WMI in C#. I can run queries to select printers, but when I try to invoke the [`RenamePrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393050(v=vs.85).aspx) method, I get an Access Denied result. I've tried running this application as administrator and creating a manifest, but I can't seem to invoke this method unless I'm actually running under the administrator account.

```
var oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);
ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection)
{
    var objectClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Printer");
    var inParams = objectClass.GetMethodParameters("RenamePrinter");

    inParams["NewPrinterName"] = "..."; // something
    ManagementBaseObject oResult = oReturn.InvokeMethod("RenamePrinter", inParams, null);

    var result = oResult["returnValue"]; // 5 = Access Denied
```

Is there some way I can invoke `RenamePrinter` under a normal user's account -- even if it means running as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this, and I've found that I can't do this with certain network printers, but with local printers it works.

What I did was launch PowerShell as local admin and run it from there:

```
public void RenamePrinter(string strCurrentName, string strNewPrinterName)
{
    var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe",
        Verb = "runas",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = "-Command \"$printer = get-wmiobject win32_printer | where { $_.Name -eq '" + strCurrentName + "' }; $printer.RenamePrinter('" + strNewPrinterName + "')\""
    };
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
}
```

I receive the same "Access Denied" error when I attempt this with network printers (maybe it's a driver thing? I don't know) but this works for local printers.